# Make sure regex does not match empty string - but with a few caveats

Tags: regex, python-3.x

There is a problem that I need to do, but there are some caveats that make it hard.

Problem: Match on all non-empty strings over the alphabet {abc} that contain at most one `a`.

*Examples*

> a
>   abc
>   bbca
>   bbcabb

*Nonexample*

> aa
>   bbaa

Caveats: You cannot use a lookahead/lookbehind.

What I have is this:

```
^[bc]*a?[bc]*$
```

but it matches empty strings. Maybe a hint? Idk anything would help

(And if it matters, I'm using python).

Comment: If you ask us how to complete your homework then how are you going to learn it yourself?

Comment: I've been trying to do it for the past like 30 minutes and I'm stuck. What I have is this: ^[bc]*a?[bc]*$  , but it matches empty strings. Maybe a hint? idk anything would help

Comment: I generally don't help with homework, but since you have the right idea with your attempt I will answer in a second.

Comment: Sounds like you could make use of the in operator to match for 'a' instead of regex. Could you add more detail to your question Vishnu? What do you want to return? A list of the matching strings?

Comment: @bobblebubble hmm the question sounds like it would also match if the string doesn't contain an 'a'. Says _at most one a_, Not must contain only one a. But the question isn't worded very clearly so maybe no.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Indeed, thank you! But should not match empty string. Maybe something like [`^(?:[bc]*a[bc]*|[bc]+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/iAtBDC/3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, the only problem is, that your current pattern matches empty strings. To prevent this you can use a [word boundary `\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to require at least one word character.

```
^\b[bc]*a?[bc]*$
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iAtBDC/4)

Another option would be to [alternate](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) in a [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Match an `a` surrounded by any amount of `[bc]` or one or more `[bc]` from start to end which could look like: [`^(?:[bc]*a[bc]*|[bc]+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/iAtBDC/3)

Answer (score 0):

The way I understood the issue was that any character in the alphabet should match, just only one **a** character.

> *Match on all non-empty strings **over the alphabet**... at most one a*

```
^[b-z]*a?[b-z]*$
```

If spaces can be included:

```
^([b-z]*\s?)*a?([b-z]*\s?)*$
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not even need a regex here, you might as well use `.count()` and a list comprehension:

```
data = """a,abc,bbca,bbcabb,aa,bbaa,something without the bespoken letter,ooo"""

def filter(string, char):
    return [word 
        for word in string.split(",")
        for c in [word.count(char)]
        if c in [0,1]]

print(filter(data, 'a'))
```

Yielding

```
['a', 'abc', 'bbca', 'bbcabb', 'something without the bespoken letter', 'ooo']
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got to positively match something excluding the empty string,
using only a, b, or c letters. But can't use assertions.

Here is what you do.

The regex `^(?:[bc]*a[bc]*|[bc]+)$`

The explanation

```
 ^                      # BOS
 (?:                    # Cluster choice
      [bc]* a [bc]*          # only 1 [a] allowed, arbitrary [bc]'s
   |                       # or,
      [bc]+                  # no [a]'s only [bc]'s ( so must be some )
 )                      # End cluster 
 $                      # EOS
```